# How does outputs effect parents in Angular if the data always flows downwards from the root?

Tags: angular, dataflow, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

This just might be a basic question but I am trying to wrap my head firmly around unidirectional data flow in Angular.

If change detection always occurs top to bottom how does @Output affects a parent component?

Am I assuming something wrong here. Somebody please explain..

Answer (score 0):

Even though the ideas of uni-directional dataflow (flux, redux, ngrx, ngxs) are wide-spread in the Angular community, Angular in itself is not fixed on this idea.

In its most basic form, Angular implements a two-way data binding:

- The @Input() decorators to allow the transfer of data from parent to child
- The @Output() decorators are used to allow emitting values from the child to the parent.

This is very suitable for small-medium sized applications with few enough components. As applications grow more complex, the uni-directional data flow pattern and its overhead become more appealing.